# Function intended to delete the first available image, deletes multiple at a time

Tags: python

The code below is supposed to delete the first available image, in a folder full of images.

But in two instances, it deleted `img_0.png` through `img_10.png` and `img_12.png` through i`mg_17.png`.

I intend for the function to delete the first available image, not multiple at a time.

```
import os, sys

i = 0
for image_file in folder_path:
    try:
        os.remove(folder_path + "img_" + str(i) + ".png")
        print("Deleted image from folder")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        i += 1
```

Comment: I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never telling the `for` loop to end, so it will continue until it finishes. Put a `break` in there to leave the loop once the `try` body completes successfully:

```
for image_file in folder_path:
    try:
        os.remove(folder_path + "img_" + str(i) + ".png")
        print("Deleted image from folder")
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        i += 1
```

Comment: @mattwelter No problem. I do agree with the other suggestion though regarding debugging. If you had put a `print` in the loop or something similar, you would have seen that it continued to loop after the first successful `remove`.